# Rating knowledge on a scale 1-10

Tags: spss, ordinal-data, continuous-data

For SPSS is rating knowledge of a nutrient on a scale of 1-10 ordinal or continuous scale variable ?

In my questionnaire I stated that 1=poor knowledge of the nutrient while 10=excellent knowledge of the nutrient

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is you who to decide, not spss. Some (minority) of procedures in spss differentiate between scale-ordinal-nominal variables. That is designed purely for automation and convenience purposes. But it is you who decides and marks the variable as this or that measurement level, if that marking comes to be necessary.

Comment: But if I use ordinal would each  number have to be given a label such as score 1 (poor knowledge) 5 (average knowledge)